# How can I use a select in update?

Tags: sql, sql-update, firebird

I have a Firebird server and I need to execute an update on a table on this server.

I should update those rows which the inner select gives back.

I have this SQL, and it runs on error at `from(`

```
update szamla_tortenet as s1
set s1.elso_atadas=1
FROM(
SELECT CEGKOD,KBIZ_ID,MIN(INS_dATE)
from SZAMLA_TORTENET AS S2
GROUP BY CEGKOD,KBIZ_ID
  )  as sq
  where s1.ins_date=sq.ins_date
```

Comment: Instead of using `update`, you might want to look at [`merge`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-merge.html) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the alias sq used in

```
where s1.ins_date=sq.ins_date
```

doesn't find ins_date as a col returned by the select statement.

```
update szamla_tortenet as s1
set s1.elso_atadas=1
where s1.ins_date=(SELECT MIN(INS_dATE) from SZAMLA_TORTENET 
GROUP BY (CEGKOD,KBIZ_ID);
```

Also if the above query fails check if the inner query is returning multiple rows which i'm pretty sure it will as it has  group .

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
update szamla_tortenet as s1
set s1.elso_atadas=1
FROM(
SELECT CEGKOD,KBIZ_ID,MIN(INS_dATE) as ins_date
from SZAMLA_TORTENET AS S2
GROUP BY CEGKOD,KBIZ_ID
  )  as sq
  where s1.ins_date=sq.ins_date
```